# Magento, In Admin page, prices attribute missing

Tags: magento, attributes, admin

I am very new to `Magento`. And My Magento version is `1.9.0.0. CE`.
As I registered third product I realized I didn't set price for the product.

So I have been searching internet to know how to set the price.
It was not easy to find what I wanted but soon I found out that I don't have
others normaly have.

```
The price button!!!
```

The `prices` button was supposed to be below `General Button`.

(Admin page : `Catalog->Manage Products->Edit` Link: 1. `General Button` 2.`Prices` 3.`Meta Information` ....)

Am I right?

What should I do now?

Comment: In your `Attribute set`, check the `Price` group if it exists.

Comment: It does exist. I saw it.

Comment: under country of manufacture

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I set the product to belong to one of attribute set
that some of plug-in made.

It was a mistake.